# Error when deploying war file create with Play! framework

Tags: playframework, war

i created a project using Play! and it works when i start as a play application,
i would like to create a war and deploy it in Tomcat.

I created the war using the following command:

```
play war -o c:\users\myapp --zip --exclude .settings:-svn:bin:eclipse:lib:test:tmp:.classpath:.project
```

But when i go to my application i have the following error:

```
@6m99il5mm
Internal Server Error (500)

No route found (In /app/views/main.html around line 13)
No route able to display file /public/lib/bootstrap-2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css (file not found) was found.

play.exceptions.NoRouteFoundException: No route found
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:80)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:282)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:202)
    at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:674)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:654)
    at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:711)
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:116)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.execute(ServletWrapper.java:574)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.run(ServletWrapper.java:565)
    at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:68)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:143)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm quite new to play, can you help me?

Thanks.

P.S. I use Play! 1.2.7.2

Comment: Did you by any chance added a external Jar file and used it in your project?